# Update support library 23.2.0 build bug

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have update the support library to 23.2.0
Since the update I get this error at build time :

> \app\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\debug\values-v11\values-v11.xml
>   Error:(67, 54) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value
>   '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').

Have you encounter this problem ?

Answer (score 26):

It was renamed a few times: Currently from version **24.0.0** on it's

```
R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material
```

Previous versions:

23.2.1 `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha`
23.2.0 `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material`

Comment: it works, simply change the abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha to abc_ic_ab_back_material

Comment: Just use it in your build.gradle `def supportV = "23.2.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportV"
`

Comment: This is missing too abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha its in 23.3.0

Comment: In v24 its called @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material but lint warns that it has private access (whatever this means)

Comment: @ for3st: "private access" means only the library should use it. If you want to use it, make a copy and paste it into your project.

Comment: So how to change it when it's located in build files only??

Answer (score 10):

This resource has been removed. See: https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.b1pysvcvl

Setting this flag should help:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

> If you have not updated yet, and are using v1.5.0 or below of the
>   Gradle plugin, you need to add the following to your app’s
>   build.gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Stops the Gradle plugin’s automatic rasterization of vectors
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  // Flag to tell aapt to keep the attribute ids around
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

Comment: same bug with these instructions

Answer (score 3):

I think Google is converting `Drawable` to `Vector Drawable` from `Android Support Library 23.2` as there is back port support in it.

For this they removed `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` in `Android Support Library 23.2`& added a vector drawable named `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material`

**Solution:**

***Add support for Vector drawable***

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
android {
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  


android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

***Replace*** `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` to `abc_ic_ab_back_material`

**Links:**

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=201835

https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.uws2k5j4j

Comment: How do you replace it? It's located in v11 build files

Answer (score 3):

Add in repository your project: **res/drawable**  new  vector data 
**abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by strictly declaring the previous AppCompat:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1'
```

Comment: i have also do this but the problem stay

Answer (score 1):

i have tested [this solution](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=201835) and work for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using the latest Material Dialogs (0.8.5.6) with the latest Support Library (23.2). Reverting to Material Dialogs 0.8.5.1 with Support Library 23.1.1 works on Android 4.

Bug report on Material Dialog's GitHub: https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/983.

Answer (score 1):

Check if any third party library is having this error, I had to update version of affolestad material dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same bug. In my case problem was in 3rd-party library, that I didn't update to the version, that use same app-compat vesrion as depency as in my project.

So try to update another libs, that use app-compat lib as depency.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the support Library **23.2.0** with the **buildToolsVersion 23.0.2** and classpath **com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0**. So, I solved it by changing the **distributionUrl** in the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file  *from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-**2.2.1**-all.zip to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-**2.14.1**-all.zip* .