# error: cannot find symbol variable abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, drawable, android-resources

I added a Fragment to my Android Studio project using `New > Fragment > Fragment (Blank)`. As a result when I try to run, the project won't compile because it cannot resolve `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` in

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

It looks like I also lost access to `android:buttonTint`

Comment: from where you try to add image from activity or fragment itself?

Comment: Activity. The act of creating the fragment through the shortcut breaks the existing code. I haven't done anything in the Fragment yet. Just creating it is the problem. Even after I delete the fragment, the problem persists.

Comment: There has to be a more meaningful way to say this than simply `try to apply grade`.

Comment: Try to put this code in your onCreate method in the fragment.         **setHasOptionsMenu(true);**

Comment: Are you compiling with `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'`?

Comment: I've had problems with abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha too missing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628572/update-support-library-23-2-0-build-bug/41635020#41635020

Answer (score 178):

The name of the resource was changed in the 23.2.0 support library.

**Modify** `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` **to** `abc_ic_ab_back_material`

Edit: 
In 23.2.1 the name of the component was changed back to abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha

Edit:
In 24.0.0 the name of the component was changed to:
abc_ic_ab_back_material

Comment: Not exactly. this new resource is marked private in appcompat-v7

Comment: I get an error: `cannot find symbol variable abc_ic_ab_back_material`

Comment: In the last version of the support library (23.2.1) they changed it back to abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha

Comment: @Jon You are absolutely correct.  You should post this as an answer on this question, and you'll get upvotes.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad it helped. I edited my answer to add the additional info

Comment: @Jon What about abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha? I have the same problem with it.

Comment: My latest build tools available is 23.0.3  I updated I don't see a 23.2.0 or 1

Comment: @JPM the version atm is 23.3 - https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne

Comment: `abc_ic_ab_back_material` can't be found on Android 4.4 and lower

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev check out this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467680/android-getting-resourcesnotfoundexception-for-abc-ic-ab-back-material

Comment: they can change in every patch lol just download it and import your project manually its best solution for all

Comment: Well, in 25.0.0 abc_ic_ab_back_material is declared `private`.

Comment: Where do you change this value?? It's automatically built

Comment: I found solution and left answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46815356/4186707

Answer (score 17):

It looks like there are no images in raster format anymore because of the vector drawable implementation in the support library. So I put this vector drawable which represents the same arrow as it was in the previous version of support library. Right click on *drawable* folder, *New -> Drawable resource file* and paste this `xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:pathData="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z" />
</vector>
```

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201835)

For APIs <21 you will have to add these properties into gradle build file:

Gradle Plugin 2.0+

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

Gradle Plugin 1.5

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

See [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

In My case, I done like this

```
final ActionBar ab = mActivity.getSupportActionBar();
             ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when updated the Android Support Library to version 23.2.0

In my case, I was using a third party library that conflicted.

I switched to the new version of the third party library to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this might not be the answer you're looking for, but this happened to me too just a few minutes ago. I was alerted by Android Studio that there was a newer version of "com.google.android.gms" and "com.android.support" available in my Gradle file - at the time, I was using 8.3.0 for the former and 23.1.1 for the latter, so I updated to 8.4.0 and 23.2.0 and that's when I got the same problem as you, and Android Studio jumped to the values-v11.xml file in the library for AFollestad's Material Dialogs, and it seems that is causing problems because it [uses the AppCompat library](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/47fqnm/support_library_232_megathread/d0d4akf).

EDIT: Just found [this](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/444#issuecomment-188675840), if you are using material-dialogs check if you're on version 0.8.5.5. If not, upgrade to it.