# Don't show back button on android toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Hi am developing an android application which has a toolbar and hamburger icon to open drawer. I have written below to implement toolbar.

xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

android:id="@+id/toolbar"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Java file:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

When I click on drawer layout, fragment opens and hamburger button changes to back arrow button.

I don't want this back arrow button. I want that irrespective of which fragment is selected there should always be hamburger icon.

Answer (score 2):

remove this if you don't want any icon:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

If you want to set custom icon then add this:

```
 ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.backarrow);
```

Comment: ... Why did you change your code? That line **is in the OP's code**. Now you are recommending removing a line that is not there! If you want to point out the line was wrong to begin with, please do so in an additional comment.

Answer (score 1):

Set your icon in the toolbar, the example is using the [default arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35720612/3994630):

```
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
```

And to hide, and show:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```