# Android: getting Resources$NotFoundException for abc_ic_ab_back_material

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-resources, android-vectordrawable

I'm getting a Resources$notfoundexception on older (pre-L) devices. I'm including the full stacktrace below.

My version of the support library is the latest (24.1.0), and I've included in my gradle file the line:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

My base theme is a noactionbar theme - "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

The crash is happening on this line in my code where I reference the back arrow in a support-toolbar in order to later change it's color:

```
@SuppressLint("PrivateResource") final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
```

What could be the cause of this? This code works fine for all users with L or above.

```
07-19 22:36:57.029 9330-9330/mypkg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {mypkg/mypkg.activites.myActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1957)
     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:673)
     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:354)
     at mypkg.base.mymethod(myactivity.java:100)
     at mypkg.mymethod(myactivity.java:100)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:511)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5341)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1954)
     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:673) 
     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:354) 
     at mypkg/mymethod(myactivity.java:100) 
     at mypkg/mymethod(myactivity.java:100) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:511) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:178) 
     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5341) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer to this turned out to be buried at the bottom of this guide:

https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.xucjbsts0

It turns out that all you need to add this line in at the beginning of the activity that will use the resource:

```
static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: I can't make it work. Added the line you mentioned, but the application crashes anyway. The stacktrace is the same, as in your question.

Comment: did you also add the useSupportLibrary line to the gradle file and are you using the latest support library version?

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing, that the problem is because your solution works only for Activities, extending AppCompatActivty, but mine is PreferenceActivity.

Comment: try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849193/how-to-add-action-bar-from-support-library-into-preferenceactivity

Comment: Thanks! Using AppCompatDelegate didn't solved crash, by using that I've added the normal toolbar and icon is not needed now.

Comment: Additionally I had to move my xml drawables from the drawable-v21 folder to the drawable folder to make them visible to older API versions. With AppCompat versions before 23.2.0 this was the way to go, as PNGs were created at build time for older API versions.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you are using AppCompatActivity instead Activity. If you're using AppCompat's theme, then you also need to use it's Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution,
in addition to `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`
is to wrap your vector drawable into another drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_your_vector"/>
</selector>
```

Might be useful when you use as a drawable for a TextView (i.e. DrawableLeft)

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is not covered all cases. **It will not work on Android 4.0.3/4.1.1/4.1.2 platform with 25.x.x support library**. The right way to fix problem with `abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml` is to override `homeAsUpIndicator` attribute in your theme. For example, my theme is inherited from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. As for value of mentioned attribute, you can use `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` or your custom 'back' drawable.

Answer (score 0):

private resources its treated differently at compile time and runtime..to fix I usually take the offending private resource and backport it to my app in my res files

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to take the resource and create it in my drawables folder. It complains that the resource isn't found, so I changed the name to make sure it wouldn't try to reference the support library version - and it still complains that the resource isn't found.

Comment: when you port it you have to change the namespace you are referring to as its no longer the android  anmespace

Answer (score 0):

I was using the application context when calling `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` which also crashes the app with `Resources$NotFoundException` and now the following message even though everything else was set up just fine:

> If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be
>   referencing it in an unsupported way. See
>   AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() for more info.

**All I had to do was to change to the view's `Context`.** :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
ContextCompat.getdrawable()
```

Try using:

```
AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable()
```