# res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml Resources$NotFoundException on Kitkat

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, android-4.4-kitkat

I DO know there is a lot of questions about this. I've already tried everything, without success.

[Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419596/resourcesnotfoundexception-file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml)

[File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739743/file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml-from-drawable-resource-id-0x7f020)

[Android: getting Resources$NotFoundException for abc_ic_ab_back_material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467680/android-getting-resourcesnotfoundexception-for-abc-ic-ab-back-material)

Yes, i've already tried downgrade `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`(and also the dependencies) to 24.x.x and 23.x.x, same error occurs.

I'm using Genymotion to emulate 4.4 android version.

Is there any possibility of being a Genymotion bug(I don't have a kitkat device to test)?

gradle of the app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maxfratane.qrcode"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I simply don't know what to do anymore. I need this app running on 4.4 devices.

Comment: Is the issue also in the Debug version or only in the Release version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two solution,

1. Make your application to use vector drawable, and use vector for back `abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml`. Lern more at [Add Multi-Density Vector Graphics](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)
2. Copy png, `ic_menu_back.png` from sdk for back icon and paste it into your project.

Comment: Works!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the possible answers and none worked for me.So if anyone is still having issue then here are my two cents:

1. Change all your android ui widgets to AppCompat widgets.
   Example : **TextView** -> **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView**
   (This is because the latest version is not having support for older android version like 4.4 kitkat)
2. I was having this issue on buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' so downgrading to '25.0.3' worked also.(Note:Not the best way as this was observed on specific devices only)