# Cannot resolve symbol abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, material-design, android-support-library

So in my project I was using standard material search icon in action bar.

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" /> </menu>
```

But if I update libreries from 23.0.1 to 24.1.1 Android Studio says:

> Cannot resolve symbol abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha

Why is that? I searched in google but didn't find answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've found an similar issue on StackOverflow: [error: cannot find symbol variable abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632576/error-cannot-find-symbol-variable-abc-ic-ab-back-mtrl-am-alpha)

The answer for topic above is:

> The name of the resource was changed in the 23.2.0 support library.
>
> **Modify** `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` **to** `abc_ic_ab_back_material`
>
> Edit:  In 23.2.1 the name of the component was changed back to
>   abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha
>
> Edit: In 24.0.0 the name of the component was changed to:
>   abc_ic_ab_back_material

All you need to do is to change name `abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha` to `abc_ic_ab_search_material`

It should work

**Update**

For API version **24.2.1** and greater use below key word.

> abc_ic_search_api_material

It will work.

Comment: abc_ic_search_api_material should work (for 24.2.1 at least)

Answer (score 1):

You can import the 'back' and 'search' material icons as vector drawables.

Right click `res/drawable` -> `New` -> `vector asset`

You can then customize the color of the drawable using DrawableCompat.setTint(). Not only is this more flexible but it will also no break in future support libraries updates.

Comment: yeah, i started usig vector asset but I noticed that all icons are black on Android 4.0 (ICS). Even if I changed color to white

Comment: `DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), Color.WHITE)` should work. Doesn't it ?

Comment: You can easily change color by modifying this XML file in drawable folder:
Change to android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF".

Comment: alternatively you can also change tint via XML
android:tint="@android:color/white"