# Updating support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am beginner in android development so this might have simple solution that i am not aware of.

I have updated android studio to newer version (1.5.1) and i have some complications with building my project from older version. So first i run build and get stopper right here :

> Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.2.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ.

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hidden"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // tests
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library')

    // tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
```

The obvious solution is to rewrite version to `23.2.0`

But then i rerun build and the real problem starts:

if file `\res\values-v11\values-v11.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MD_Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_minor</item>

        <item name="md_divider">@color/md_divider_white</item>
        <item name="md_list_selector">@drawable/md_selector_dark</item>
        <item name="md_btn_stacked_selector">@drawable/md_selector_dark</item>
        <item name="md_btn_positive_selector">@drawable/md_btn_selector_dark</item>
        <item name="md_btn_neutral_selector">@drawable/md_btn_selector_dark</item>
        <item name="md_btn_negative_selector">@drawable/md_btn_selector_dark</item>

        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha</item>

        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MD_WindowAnimation</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>file continues...
```

following error:

> Error:(15, 54) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').

Now i did my research and according to [Update support library 23.2.0 build bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628572/update-support-library-23-2-0-build-bug/35628668) I should just rename the resource by its new file name but the file is generated and should not be changed and after rebuild it gets regenerated so i cant seem to fing a way out of this trouble.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to change this external library to newest version supporting changes in new support library v23.2.0

```
compile ('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.6@aar')
```

For some reason it has to be done manually.

Comment: THANK YOU. It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the warning using the 23.2.0.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'
```

About the issue.

> Error:(15, 54) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').

You are referring a **private resource**.

As you can check in the [google tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201835) a possible solution is
to try change the reference of `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` to `abc_ic_ab_back_material` in your style.

Comment: So if I understand this right, the problem is in my layout files and not in this generated file ? Is there any way how can i fing exact place i am referencing to this value and correct it ?

Comment: Not sure I've understood your comment. In the values-v11.xml reported above you can find this reference.

Comment: Yes, but this file is generated when i am building my project, any changes are removed and file is regenerated to this exact form.

Comment: Sorry. It was no clear. In this case you using a dependency that has the issue. You have to address the author to solve the issue

Comment: Judging by this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201835&q=label%3ADefect-27357712&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) It is known problem with support library