# No resource found that matches the given name error in android after updating android studio and build tools

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.2

After updating my android studio to 2.2 preview 4 version i have this errors:

```
Error:(93, 54) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').
```

my build.gradle (app) is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.arisa.kalahroodfinal"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile files('/Users/Bmaster/AndroidStudioProjects/KalahroodFinal/libraries/jsoup-1.9.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
/*
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
*/
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

and i use : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
I have changed build tools to 23 version but I already have that error!!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` with `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material`

This resource has been removed in this library see [this](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.b1pysvcvl)

**RESOURCES** 
[Update support library 23.2.0 build bug Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628572/update-support-library-23-2-0-build-bug/35628668) Also other searching results for explanation

Comment: tnx for answering, but how i can replace!!! after clicking on error v11/values-v11.xml opened that i can't change name of @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha to @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material

Comment: your welcome for sure, try toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material); and tell me what you got