# Error:(2324, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'navigationIcon' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha')

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-support-library

I'm having issues with an older project that I can't seem to resolve. Whenever I try to build the project, I'm getting the error:

Error:(2324, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'navigationIcon' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').

I've updated my app build.gradle as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.excelicalcom.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
ext {
supportLibVersion = '25.1.1'  // variable that can be referenced to keep        support libs consistent
}

dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"

compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

compile "com.android.support:percent:${supportLibVersion}"

compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}" // VectorDrawableCompat
compile "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}" // AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat

compile "com.android.support:transition:${supportLibVersion}"

compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"

//circular imageview

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.0'

compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.1.+'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
//Facebook SDK
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
//Picasso
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What's you support lib version? Maybe could be the same problem described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628572/update-support-library-23-2-0-build-bug/35628668

Comment: Well I am currently on 25.1.1, so that issue should be resolved, right?

Comment: No, they removed the drawable you are searching, you need to replace the reference with this: @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material

Comment: I need to replace the reference inside the values.xml? Or do I need to find where the icon is used inside a layout xml file?

Comment: You need to find where the icon is used in your layouts file. If you are not able to find it that means it's a library problem. In this case you should check and upgrade all the dependencies of your app to the latest version and see if the problem goes away. If even in this case the app is still not compiling correctly. You should go back to support library version 23.2.1 where the properties was still there