# Android Support library Build V 25 error

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-styles

I'm getting error in values v11 style value when I update my support library version from 23.4.0 to 25

Here are my configurations :

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 64
        versionName "2.0.8"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

And my support library :

```
def SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '25.0.0'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile("com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION") {
        force = true;
    }
    compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
```

The error I'm getting :

```
Error:(109, 54) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').
Error:(109, 54) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').
```

But when I reverted the support library version back to 23, it built just fine.

What am I missing? I just updated my Android SDK manager support library to the latest and still getting the same error.

Comment: The name of the drawable was changed. Google sadly does that from time to time :/

Comment: This is what irks me, some of source of support libraries from google just poorly documented

Comment: The drawable resources are actually marked as nonpublic in Android Studio. This is Google's way of saying 'don't use them directly in your projects'. What I usually do is create a new XML file in values folder where I reference AppCompat's drawables with a <drawable ... /> tag and use that proxy variable in my layout files instead. This way when Google changes anything I need to make the changes in a single place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 
    `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` with `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material`

this is the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628572/update-support-library-23-2-0-build-bug)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to abc_ic_ab_back_material